# How to stub two chained ActiveRecord methods in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a piece of code like this:

```
Green::Trees.where(id: ids).find_each do |tree|
  tree.grow!
end
```

What's a good way to stub `find_each` so that in each iteration, it returns a tree that I define in a let block in a test like this:

```
let(:tree) { create(:tree) }
let(:tree_ids) { [tree.id] }
```

What can I do?

Should I do something like this?

```
allow(Green::Tree).to receive(:where).and_return(Green::Tree)
allow(Green::Tree).to receive(:find_each).and_yield(tree)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RSpec gives you two ways to stub chained method calls.

The succinct way is `receive_message_chain`:

```
allow(Green::Trees).to receive_message_chain(:where, :find_each).and_yield(tree)
```

That doesn't let you specify arguments, however, although it often isn't important to do so.

If you care about arguments, you can do it like this:

```
results = double
allow(Green::Tree).to receive(:where).with(id: ids).and_return(results)
allow(results).to receive(:find_each).and_yield(tree)
```

What you wrote would work, but it's incorrect since `where` doesn't return the class `Green::Tree`, but an ActiveRecord relation. `Green::Tree` does implement `find_each`, but it's a different method with the same name as the one on the relation. Very confusing!

Comment: That works? What if `where` takes arguments? Do I need to specify then in that allow statement?

Comment: If where takes arguments, do it the long way and add `with` to the first `allow`. `receive_message_chain` doesn't support arguments.

Comment: but then what about the second `find_each`. Do I just chain together two `receive`s and two `with`?

Comment: You would add `with` after `receive(:find_each)`. I added the first `with` to my answer; if that's not clear enough, add arguments to your `find_each` and I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I misspoke. My where has arguments (id: ids) but my find_each jsut takes a block. Your answer I think is sufficient. Thanks!